# accessing json inside request body

Tags: java, android, json

I am using an API provided to us by someone else and it returns it this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://ywers.com">
[{"Name":"Edward", "LastName":"Jones", "Address":"{accepted}"}
,{"Name":"Carlos",  "LastName":"Ramirez", "Address":"{Rejected}"}]</string>
```

what is the best way to extract the JSON and also, how can I brake the JSON into separate objects like

```
{"Name":"Edward", "LastName":"Jones", "Address":"{accepted}"}
and
{"Name":"Carlos",  "LastName":"Ramirez", "Address":"{Rejected}"}
```

As you can see one of the fields returns with a bracket inside. Another issue i am having is that i think the brackets are coming as question signs when i print the response.

Comment: A good way to extract the JSON might be to use an XML parsing library, since that is what the JSON is wrapped in.

Comment: Why would anyone do this? Ask your colleagues to either give data in XML or in JSON. Else you will not be getting the benefit of either. :)

Comment: this is soooo wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, parse the XML to get the embedded JSON as

```
String XML = "<Your XML Response>";
XPathExpression xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance()
                         .newXPath().compile("/*[local-name()='string']");
String json = xpath.evaluate(new InputSource(new StringReader(XML)));
```

Then, parse the JSON using any JSON parser. I've used the [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) Java parser below.

```
JSONArray jsonRoot = new JSONArray(json.trim());
System.out.println(jsonRoot.getJSONObject(0).getString("Address")); // {accepted}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the JSON is returned inside of XML, you will have to 1) use an XML parser to get the contents of the `<string>` tag.  Once you have that, you can 2) pass it to a JSON parser.

- For step 1, this might help get you started: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html
- For step 2, take a look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html

Hope that helps!

Comment: Also note that there are many XML/JSON parsers available for use with Android.  You'll just have to make sure the one you use has a license compatible with your project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the followings:

1. Parse the response using XML parser. You can use the [Simple XML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php) framework.
2. Now parse the content of string tag value which is JSON content using Google JSON parser, [GOSN](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)